# Get webpage html(css,js) JavaFX

Tags: java, html, css

I want to save web page at `JavaFX`, I write this code, this code only save webpage `html`, but I need `CSS`,`JavaScript` of same page.

```
SampleController sp=new SampleController();
WebEngine webEngine =sp.web.getEngine();
webEngine.load(sp.url.getText());                 
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
  txtFileURL.getText() +"/"+txtname+".htm"
);
out.write(
  ((String) webEngine.executeScript(
    "document.documentElement.innerHTML"
  )).getBytes()
);
out.flush();
out.close();
```